# mysql command not recognizing a string in Japanese

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert into my table on the server using a terminal mysql command, and if my command contains any Japanese text, blank text gets inserted in to the db column or mysql exits with an error. However, if i save the same command into an sql file and import the sql file with a `source` command everything works fine. Is there any way to be able to insert japanese text into db straight from the terminal command instead of having to save into a file ?

EG
running the following code from the terminal using the mysql insert command

```
INSERT into tblname 
values('FES', 'whatevertextなし', 18, 0, 0, now(), 1, now(), 1, null, now());
```

results in

```
'FES', 'whatevertext', 18, 0, 0, now(), 1, now(), 1, null, now()
```

and the following errors:
`Level: Warning Message: Incorrect string value: '\xE3\x81\x82\xE3\x81\x82...' for column 'firstname' at row 1. 2 rows in set (0.00 sec)`

If i copy and paste the code above into an sql file and execute `source`, everything gets inserted properly. But obviously this takes a lot longer

Also if the string only contains japanese characters, the query results with error. Is there no way to execute the above command from the terminal?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @RobertColumbia `Query OK, 1 row affected, 2 warnings (0.01 sec)`

Comment: `Level: Warning Message: Incorrect string value: '\xE3\x81\x82\xE3\x81\x82...' for column 'firstname' at row 1. 2 rows in set (0.00 sec)`

Comment: You should copy that into the question.

Comment: I am guessing the error is about the mysql encoding, but the same query works from an sql file